# Ubuntu installer does not recognize existing OS and partitions

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, toshiba-laptop

I just bought a Toshiba Satellite L55-B5276 (i-5 core, 8 GB RAM) with pre-installed Windows 8. I brought it to our IT guy and he swiped off Windows 8 and replaced it with Windows 7. He partitioned the hard drive to put on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. However, when he got to the installer and selected "Something else" there was only a "free space" option for the whole disk space, which, if partitioned would swipe off Windows 7. He put Ubuntu on a virtual disk within Windows for now. However, I would prefer to have a real partition.

Windows is installed on a non-EFI mode. Would that make any difference?

I found this entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481423/new-laptop-windows-8-1-attempting-dual-install-ubuntu-installer-doesnt-see I tried the two commands suggested there and got some warnings.

For *sudo parted -l* I got this:

```
/dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. However, 
it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should. Perhaps it 
was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT msdos 
partition table. Is this a GPT paritition table? Yes/No?
```

For *sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda* I got this message:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out! 
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table 
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:

MBR: MBR only
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the 
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)

1-MBR
2-GPT
3-Create blank GPT
```

**So my questions are:**

1) does the boot mode matter in this case?

2) Is my hard drive broken and I should return the computer or is this an evil way to prohibit dual booting?

3) Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the partitions in the "Disk Management" tool of Windows 7? Ensure the other partition also formatted and ready to use. To access "Disk Management", Computer > Manage > Disk Management.

Comment: Never take your computer back to that guy.

Comment: You need to shrink the W7 partition in order to allow a free area for the new OS. If you boot the LiveCD in try-out mode you can use `gparted` to do any partition manipulation you need. You are encouraged to back up first.